# IIS 6.0 stops serving Classic ASP page suddenly

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-6

I have **Classic ASP** web site hosted on IIS 6.0 (It's a production server). It stops serving pages intermittently say for every 1 week or 10 days. after IISRESET again it works fine.

- Verified IIS web server logs and there were no request hits found from the logs.
- Verfieid HTTPError logs. Nothing found abnormal.
- We already configured Application pooling to improve the performance for the website and recycling    the worker process every 24 hrs.But, didn't help us much.

Could you please advise me in resolving the issue and what is causing this issue.

Comment: Check the system event logs too.  Sometimes that will spot the error.  I have seen this issue when you run out of resources as well.  Check the memory pressure when you do an IIS reset and then a couple of days out.  Finally it could be a connection limit issue if something is keeping connections open on the box.  Netstat -a at the command line will help you find if that is the issue.  Again when you do IISReset do netstat -a and then a couple of days later and compare the output.

Comment: Check for the incoming traffic, it may be search crawlers that's freezing the site.

Comment: Jeff, We have followed the steps as suggested but vain. could you suggest is there a way to address the issue. Thank you!!